# incorrect mouse pointer in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: firefox, mouse, banshee

My ubuntu is been acting little weired 
[image]

please refer to attached screenshot

the pointer is showing on '**in my head**' but it get clicked on '**In my remains**' 
this issue is same on firefox.

the pointer is **shifted few positions**

For better understanding :-

see the **screenshot** of Thunderbird with blackbox.

the pointer is **not accurate**

more screenshot :-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Known (old) bug. See "[Wrong mouse-coordinates in the window after minimize/maximize of after return from fullscreen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1306550)". There are also several workaround suggestions in the comments:

- "switch to ohter desktop and come back (CTRL+SHITF+arrow)"
- "enable "switch between minimized windows" in Unity Tweak Tool"
- "minimize and maximize again for the problem to go away."
- etc.